# R: Keep replacing values in the next column

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` generated from the code below.

```
set.seed(1)
x1<-data.frame(cbind(paste("I",sample(1:10,3),sep=""), sample(50:80,3)))
x2<-data.frame(cbind(paste("I",sample(1:10,3),sep=""), sample(50:80,3)))
x3<-data.frame(cbind(paste("I",sample(1:10,3),sep=""), sample(50:80,3)))
df<-Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, by="X1", all=T), list(x1,x2,x3))
colnames(df)<-c("ID","X1","X2","X3")
> df
   ID  X1   X2   X3
1  I3   78 <NA> <NA>
2  I4   56 <NA>   71
3  I5   76 <NA> <NA>
4 I10 <NA>   51   78
5  I6 <NA>   56 <NA>
6  I9 <NA>   55 <NA>
7  I7 <NA> <NA>   65
```

Values in X1 are the oldest and those in X3 are the newest. What I need to have is a dataframe with the updated values from the oldest to the newest while ignoring NA. The data frame I'd like to have looks like

```
   ID  NewX
1  I3   78
2  I4   71
3  I5   76
4 I10   78
5  I6   56
6  I9   55
7  I7   65
```

Although there are only three variables in this example, my real data has more than 15 variables. So I'm trying to avoid updating manually. Any idea would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the values using `row/column` indexing.  Get the column index of the non-NA element for each row with `max.col` (specifying the `ties.method` as "last"), `cbind` the row index i.e. sequence of rows and extract the matching element of dataset based on these indices, `cbind` with the first column i.e. 'ID' column

```
cbind(df[1], NewX = df[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)),
                        max.col(!is.na(df[-1]), "last"))])
#   ID NewX
#1  I3   78
#2  I4   71
#3  I5   76
#4 I10   78
#5  I6   56
#6  I9   55
#7  I7   65
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` with `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(2:4, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))  %>% # change factor class
  transmute(ID, NewX = coalesce(X3, X2, X1)) 
  # if there are many columns, convert the column names to symbol and evaluate
  # transmute(ID, NewX = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[4:2])))
#   ID NewX
#1  I3   78
#2  I4   71
#3  I5   76
#4 I10   78
#5  I6   56
#6  I9   55
#7  I7   65
```

Comment: Thanks much. I learned `max.col` function from you . A very minor edit would be, "Get the column index....for each "COLUMN' with `max.col`... ?

Comment: @ShinziKatoh  Glad to know that it worked.  What i meant is that we are getting the column index of the logical matrix (`!is.na(`)  where TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0 (NA).  By indicating `"last"`, it gets the last TRUE value among the TRUE columns